# Angular checkbox filter function not working with Selenium automation

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, filter, automation, dropdown

FE developed w/Angular 16. I have a checkbox dropdown to filter things but I need to click somewhere in the page in order to filter work. With Selenium Java automation framework, web elements are located and I can see during automation checkbox is selected from dropdown. But I couldn't make the filter function work. It clicks on the other web elements, refresh button but filter somehow does not filter out the table. I tried double click, JS blur(), etc... Any idea what might be causing that issue? Any resolution? Thanks in advance!

Tried to click on other filters, web elements, refresh button, JS blur()... I was expecting table to filter based on the selection